# When does the UnderlyingSystemType differ from the current Type instance

Tags: c#, .net, clr, base-class-library

`System.Type` contains an `UnderlyingSystemType` property. MSDN [states](httpS://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.underlyingsystemtype.aspx) that it:

> Indicates the type provided by the common language runtime that
>   represents this type.

In most cases, this property simply returns the current `Type` instance.

My question is, in what circumstances does this property *not* return the current `Type` instance itself. And in those cases, what sort of type will be the current `Type` instance and the returned underlying system type be?

Comment: Can´t tell you exactly why but here is an article about the fact (http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/02/when-is-a-type-not-a-type.html)

Comment: http://catalog.codeproject.com/Questions/366922/Whats-the-difference-between-UnderlyingSystemType contains some info on this.

Comment: I'll just wait for Jon Skeet. He never let me down.

Comment: Interesting... [When a type is not a type](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/02/when-is-a-type-not-a-type.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To be honest I never did it by myself, but I know that it is possible to create your own `RuntimeType` like  definition of your specified type.

If you notice the `Type` class is abstract and has a lot of abstract memebers. What happens is that *your* type (whatever is it) automatically creates `RuntimeType` derived from `Type` class and implements it for your type.

So the property `UnderlyingSystemType` in case of orindary `RuntimeType` will return `Type` property equal value, in case of overriden implementation, instead, (that is for influencing relfection behavior, but I repeat I personally never did this before), will return user-defined type value.

**EDIT**

Actually the link provided by guys in comments is a good one:

[When is a Type not a Type?](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/02/when-is-a-type-not-a-type.html)